# The argument type 'Query<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'. (users_api.dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

The argument type 'Query<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'.

[{
"resource": "/d:/dating_app/lib/api/users_api.dart",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#4",
"code": {
"value": "argument_type_not_assignable",
"target": {
"$mid": 1,
"external": "https://dart.dev/diagnostics/argument_type_not_assignable",
"path": "/diagnostics/argument_type_not_assignable",
"scheme": "https",
"authority": "dart.dev"
}
},
"severity": 8,
"message": "The argument type 'Query<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'.",
"source": "dart",
"startLineNumber": 36,
"startColumn": 36,
"endLineNumber": 36,
"endColumn": 46
}]

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dating_app/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:dating_app/models/user_model.dart';
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';

class UsersApi {
  /// Get firestore instance
  ///
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  /// Get all users
  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getUsers({
    required List<DocumentSnapshot> dislikedUsers,
  }) async {
    /// Build Users query
    Query usersQuery = _firestore
        .collection(C_USERS)
        .where(USER_STATUS, isEqualTo: 'active')
        .where(USER_LEVEL, isEqualTo: 'user');

    // Filter the User Gender
    usersQuery = UserModel().filterUserGender(usersQuery);

    // Instance of Geoflutterfire
    final Geoflutterfire geo = new Geoflutterfire();

    /// Get user settings
    final Map<String, dynamic>? settings = UserModel().user.userSettings;

    // // Get user geo center
    final GeoFirePoint center = geo.point(
        latitude: UserModel().user.userGeoPoint.latitude,
        longitude: UserModel().user.userGeoPoint.longitude);

    final allUsers = await geo
        .collection(collectionRef: usersQuery)
        .within(
            center: center,
            radius: settings![USER_MAX_DISTANCE].toDouble(),
            field: USER_GEO_POINT,
            strictMode: true)
        .first;

    // Remove the current user profile - If choosed to see everyone
    if (allUsers.isNotEmpty) {
      allUsers.removeWhere(
          (userDoc) => userDoc[USER_ID] == UserModel().user.userId);
    }

    /// Remove Disliked Users in list
    if (dislikedUsers.isNotEmpty) {
      dislikedUsers.forEach((dislikedUser) {
        allUsers.removeWhere(
            (userDoc) => userDoc[USER_ID] == dislikedUser[DISLIKED_USER_ID]);
      });
    }

    // Get Liked Profiles
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> likedProfiles = (await _firestore
            .collection(C_LIKES)
            .where(LIKED_BY_USER_ID, isEqualTo: UserModel().user.userId)
            .get())
        .docs;

    // Remove Liked Profiles
    if (likedProfiles.isNotEmpty) {
      likedProfiles.forEach((likedUser) {
        allUsers.removeWhere(
            (userDoc) => userDoc[USER_ID] == likedUser[LIKED_USER_ID]);
      });
    }

    /// Sort by newest
    allUsers.sort((a, b) {
      final DateTime userRegDateA = a[USER_REG_DATE].toDate();
      final DateTime userRegDateB = b[USER_REG_DATE].toDate();
      return userRegDateA.compareTo(userRegDateB);
    });

    final int minAge = settings[USER_MIN_AGE];
    final int maxAge = settings[USER_MAX_AGE];

    // Filter Profile Ages
    return allUsers.where((DocumentSnapshot user) {
      // Get User Birthday
      final DateTime userBirthday = DateTime(
          user[USER_BIRTH_YEAR], user[USER_BIRTH_MONTH], user[USER_BIRTH_DAY]);

      /// Get user profile age to filter
      final int profileAge = UserModel().calculateUserAge(userBirthday);
      // Return result
      return profileAge >= minAge && profileAge <= maxAge;
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

erorr line *.collection(collectionRef: usersQuery) error on **usersQuery*** bold word is red on visual code studio that is the error

i dont know how to explain the error again

Comment: you should add more information about the question instead of giving an error message

Comment: error line on  .collection(collectionRef: usersQuery) error on usersQuery i dont know how to explain that red on visual code studio

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

In this line:

```dart
 final allUsers = await geo
        .collection(collectionRef: usersQuery)
        .within(
            center: center,
            radius: settings![USER_MAX_DISTANCE].toDouble(),
            field: USER_GEO_POINT,
            strictMode: true)
        .first;
```

Geoflutterfire's [collection method](https://pub.dev/documentation/geoflutterfire/latest/geoflutterfire/Geoflutterfire/collection.html) requires a query of type `Query<Map<String, dynamic>>` but you're passing a query of type `Query` i.e `usersQuery`.

## Solution:

Specify the type for `userQuery` as `Map<String, dynamic>` by doing the following:

Update this line:

```dart
Query usersQuery = _firestore
        .collection(C_USERS)
        .where(USER_STATUS, isEqualTo: 'active')
        .where(USER_LEVEL, isEqualTo: 'user');
```

to this:

```dart
 Query<Map<String, dynamic>> usersQuery = _firestore
      .collection(C_USERS)
      .where(USER_STATUS, isEqualTo: 'active')
      .where(USER_LEVEL, isEqualTo: 'user');
```

Comment: now error on     // Filter the User Gender
    usersQuery = UserModel().filterUserGender(usersQuery);

Comment: What does the error say exactly?

Comment: Query<Object?> filterUserGender(Query<Object?> query)
Type: Query<Object?> Function(Query<Object?>) package:dating_app/models/user_model.dart

A value of type 'Query<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Query<Map<String, dynamic>>'.dartinvalid_assignment

Comment: Please post your `UserModel().filterUserGender` method

Comment: on that scripts  // Filter the User Gender

Comment: I was asking for you to post the actual `filterUserGender` method.

Comment: But from the error message, it appears you need to update the `filterUserGender` method definition to this `filterUserGender(Query<Map<String, dynamic>> query)`.

Comment: i change usersQuery = UserModel().filterUserGender(usersQuery) as Query<Map<String, dynamic>>; error is gone

Comment: Oh, great! Glad to know.